# Magento, retrieve configurable product price, discount price for simple product

Tags: php, magento

I'm creating a product feed for several client using my extension. For this specific client, they have different price setup compared to others. They have configurable products and under that simple products  connected to configurable one. Their prices usually match but when they put a product under discount, they only set discounted price to configurable product. In their site, discount price getting read from configurable one. But in my extension, I'm reading products one by one and when I get the price of the simple product, it returns me non-discounted one. I'm using the following code:

```
$price = $product->getPrice();
$discount_price = $product->getFinalPrice();
```

Is there an easy way or anyway to retrieve configurable product's discounted price while processing simple product?

Edit: I'm also posting orders after I get the product by its SKU. I'm having the same price issue in there as well.